# How can I make xVal work with my extended Html.ValidationImage?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, xval

I have extended the ASP.NET MVC Html Helper to include my own ValidationImage that outputs an image rather than the standard  tags.  Details are shown within the [StackOverflow Question: How do I extend Html.ValidationMessage so that I can include an image as the error?](http://ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265857/how-do-i-extend-html-validationmessage-so-that-i-can-include-an-image-as-the-erro)

I would like this to integrate well with [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/) now.  What would be the best method for doing this?  How would I change the [xVal.jquery.validate.js](http://xval.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/21650?projectName=xval#279846) file to work with my error images?

Currently I have adjusted the [xVal.jquery.validate.js](http://xval.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/21650?projectName=xval#279846) file to work with the img tag rather than the standard span tag.  I am receiving an error when the [xVal.jquery.validate.js](http://xval.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/21650?projectName=xval#279846) plug-in is trying to append something to the img tag.  I assume it is trying to append the error text to the image tag which would cause an error.

What would be the best way to modify the [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/) plug-in so that the error is added to the title attribute and the img tag is displayed into view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to do this is to put your image into the attributes e.g.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="<img src=\"error.gif\">")]
public string Forename { get; set; }
```

But its not ideal. Maybe a helper class could populate the error message or something like this.

Comment: Actually, Id be interested to hear if you have a better method as your question was posted some time ago now :)

Comment: I beleive that I created the Html helper class to use the images in the error messages.